# Sails.js - Is there intended support for a "one-way-many" association

Tags: associations, sails.js, waterline

I'm interested in a `one-way-many` association. To explain:

```
// Dog.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        favorateFoods: {
            collection: 'food',
            dominant: true
        }
    }
};
```

and

```
// Food.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        cost: {
            type: 'integer'
        }
    }
};
```

In other words, I want a `Dog` to be associated w/ `many` `Food` entries, but as for `Food`, I don't care which `Dog` is associated.

If I actually implement the above, believe it or not it works. However, the `table` for the `association` is named in a very confusing manner - even more confusing than normal ;)

`dog_favoritefoods__food_favoritefoods_food`, with `id`, `dog_favoritefoods`, and `food_favoritefoods_food`.

`REST` `blueprints` function with the `Dog` model just fine, I don't see anything that "looks bad" except for the funky table name.

So, the question is, is it supposed to work this way, and does anyone see something that might potentially go haywire?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be ok.

However, there does not really seem any reason to not complete the association for a Many to Many. The reason would be because everything is already being created for that single collection. The join table and its attributes are already there. The only thing missing in this equation is the reference back on food.

I could understand if putting the association on food were to create another table or create another weird join, but that has already been done. There really is no overhead to creating the other association.

So in theory you might as well create it, thus avoiding any potential conflicts unless you have a really compelling reason not to?

Edited: Based on the comments below we should note that one could experience overhead in lift based the blueprints and dynamic finders created.

Comment: I actually disagree on overhead. While it definitely doesn't add to storage, it does add load to the blueprints. Add several other models, Cat, Rabbit, etc. If each model has a many-to-many with Food, GET blueprint populating by default, it takes a performance hit. Maybe it's more noticeable in mysql, but we were talking 10x. Meaning, a blueprint taking ~50ms consistently with populate off, ~500ms+ with populate on. You can overwrite the blueprints, turn populate off, several options, but if you can avoid it through the configuration of the models, that seems like the best choice.

Comment: You are correct. I think that would be a valid consideration then. I know I was going to just the dynamic finders, but I think those have all been turned off by default the latest version? If not, those would also be a consideration on lift.