# How to create a one-way one to many relationship in SailsJS?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to create a **unit** model, that has many **objectives**. The user will be able to create their own **units**. Each **objective** will already be determined, they'll simply be chosen by the user to make up the **unit**. The  **objectives**, therefore, will not need to have any knowledge about the user's **unit**.

The documentation shows how to achieve a single one way relationship - what's the correct way to do this if there are multiple?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198701/sails-js-is-there-intended-support-for-a-one-way-many-association/

Comment: Just what I was looking for - thanks! I'll clear this...